# JavaScript Object loop - Filter and show duplicates once

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have some code that works kind of like this:

```
var date = new Date();
var userMessage = {
    UserName: "Charlie",
    LastOnline: date.toDateString(),
    Name: "Charlie"
};
Object.keys(userMessage).forEach(function(user) {
   if (userMessage[user] == "Charlie") {
     document.write("Welcome Charlie!");
   }
});
```

However this works fine but i only would like the document to write "Welcome Charlie!" once. It will be possible that the user will have the same field twice, How would i limit this to once?

Soon this function will be wrapped with an angularJS ng-repeat. Maybe its possible to do this once with a filter?

Fiddle Link:
https://jsfiddle.net/dj5ka4g6/1/

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah exactly, But then if one of the messages had a reply i would only show a modal once rather than several times. I haven't created that yet and wanted to start with a different base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to get the object's values with `Object.values`, deduplicate via a `Set`, and then iterate:

```js
var date = new Date();
var userMessage = {
  UserName: "Charlie",
  LastOnline: date.toDateString(),
  Name: "Charlie"
};

[...new Set(Object.values(userMessage))]
  .forEach((val) => {
    if (val === 'Charlie') console.log('Welcome Charlie');
  });
```

Or, if, as your code seems to imply, you're just checking whether `Charlie` is included in the values, then use the `.includes` method:

```js
var date = new Date();
var userMessage = {
  UserName: "Charlie",
  LastOnline: date.toDateString(),
  Name: "Charlie"
};

if (Object.values(userMessage).includes('Charlie')) {
  console.log('Welcome Charlie');
}
```

If you just need the deduplicated array, then:

```js
var date = new Date();
var userMessage = {
  UserName: "Charlie",
  LastOnline: date.toDateString(),
  Name: "Charlie"
};

console.log([...new Set(Object.values(userMessage))]);
```

Comment: That's really nice! Looks like its what i need, How does the ellipses work? Never seen that kinda code before but it looks beautiful

Comment: It's called spread syntax, it's a bit nicer than `concat`, see MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[].some` to iterate until you find at least one good value:

```js
var date = new Date();
var userMessage = {
    UserName: "Charlie",
    LastOnline: date.toDateString(),
    Name: "Charlie"
};
Object.keys(userMessage).some(function(user) {
   if (userMessage[user] == "Charlie") {
     console.log("Welcome Charlie!");
     return true;
   }
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 0):

Just use old for loop.

```js
const users = Object.keys(userMessage).map((key) => userMessage[key]);

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  if (users[i] === 'Charlie') {
    console.log(`Welcome ${users[i]}`);
    break;
  }
}
```